# Texlive upgrade and missing packages

Tags: texlive, enumitem, ubuntu

Every time I install a new TeX Live version (the "full" one) on Ubuntu, I encounter some lack of backward compatibility (e.g. missing packages or changed commands in existing packages) and some of my LaTeX projects stop working. Sometimes it takes a lot of time to understand how to fix the problem.

What is a proper way of dealing with such issues? Is there a list of packages that were removed in a new "full" TeX Live version, compared to the previous one?

To be more concrete, this time I have a problem with `enumitem` package, which is not included TeX Live 2018 and cannot be installed with `tlmgr`.

Comment: Erh, `enumitem` **is** included in TeX Live 2018. Are you sure you do not have two latex installations and is thus using the wrong one? Look in the log file.

Comment: IIRC, the `enumitem` package might be included in `texlive-latex-extra`, which is a _different_ package than `texlive` in some Linux distributions.

Comment: @daleif I am sure, I have only one installation. If I do "ls /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*/*.sty", I don't see enumitem there

Comment: @campa I have used the install script from the texlive website, not the Ubuntu package manager (because apt only allows to install old outdated stuff which is bad in case of latex).

Comment: `enumitem` should be installed in a *full* TeX live (and it should be possible to install it with `tlmgr` if it is not present already). Occasionally, packages are removed from TeX live (often for legal/license reasons), but I wouldn't have thought that that would create such an issue (as many of those packages don't seem to be used all that much). Compatibility issues are much more likely to arise from changes within a package and those are indeed hard to keep track of.

Comment: @moewe Actually, I have just tried to run tlmgr with a different server. When I was installing TeX live, it used a Spanish server, and now probably some US one. And there it actually does have enumitem and I can install it with tlmgr. It is weird that there are such inconsistencies, I always thought all the servers have the same packages.

Comment: A better way to look is probably to use find or even better `kpsewhich enumitem.sty`

Comment: @daleif I tried this one too and it shows nothing. Apparently the problem is with the wrong server (see my comment above).

Comment: Also beware since the package was updated recently the default 2018 is "frozen" against recent updates

Comment: You might have gotten a really bad repository. Care to tell which one? But `enumitem` should have been there at the beginning, unless you did not install a full one to begin with.

Comment: Mhh, normally all servers should more or less contain the same packages (you can see their sync delay to the main server at https://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon). It could be that you hit a bad one. But then that must have been extremely bad luck if a common package like `enumitem` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

**Backup old texlive versions!**

You asked how to deal with different versions and developments of texlive over the years, especially changing or later deprecated packages. We found out that you got your texlive installation from an unreliable server and you simply installed the missing package.

But texlive 2019 will come soon with changes that may or may not break some documents. How to deal with that?

If you have enough space on your HDD / SDD / whatever, then keep some older installations. I will install texlive 2019 *beside* texlive 2018 and at a later date delete the really old texlive 2016. All texlive installations reside in .../texlive/year, while my local packages on the level of the machine (not on user-level) reside in .../texlive/texmf-local and remain untouched from the installation of a new texlive.

If texlive 2019 breaks something, I just change the path and am back on texlive 2018 / 17 / 16 for this document.

And to be really on the safe side, I became a member of my local TUG (tex-user-group) and enjoy every year receiving a DVD providing texlive and CTAN. I'm keeping them dry and clean, you never know. OK, I'm not sure texlive 2009 would even run, but at least I could import an old package, just in case...

Comment: I don't think his download was necessarily from "an unreliable server", it is often an issue of glitching between servers and happens more frequently than a scratched dvd. Your suggestion to keep 2019 2018 2017 and ditch 2016 once happy is sensible and good industry practice, however most of us live on the edge of the copper precipice so download piecemeal bits as required .